# Python. Metaclass. Переопределение атрибутов

Tags: python

```
class Meta(type) :
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct) :
        cls.attr = 'name'
        super().__init__(name, bases, dct)

class A(metaclass = Meta) :
    attr = 'new_name'

print(A.attr) # name
```

Как в таком случае переопределить атрибут класса?

Comment: вы спрашиваете: как в классе `A` определить `attr` атрибут, если `A` использует `Meta` метакласс, который уже устанавливает `attr` атрибут на классе? То есть как изменить поведение предоставляемое метаклассом в данном случае? Вы хотите `A.attr == 'new_name'` или `A().attr == 'new_name'` или оба как атрибут класса так и атрибут объекта?

Comment: @jfs, да, нужно переопределить атрибут класса (изменить поведение, предоставляемое метаклассом). Класса, не объекта. (A.attr = 'new_name'). Это возможно? Т.е. это возможно, конечно, но вариант, например, после объявления класса, написать затем A.attr = 'new_attr' - не подходит.

Comment: Если не нравится как класс сейчас создаётся, то другой метакласс можно передать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно объяснить, добавив немного лишних print'ов:

```
class Meta(type):
    print("Meta body")

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print("Meta init for {name}".format(name=name))
        cls.attr = 'name'
        super().__init__(name, bases, dct)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        print("Meta new for {name}".format(name=name))
        print(classdict)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)


class A(metaclass = Meta):
    print("A body")
    attr = 'new_name'

    def __init__(self):
        # Очевидно, не вызывается, потому что объект не создается
        print("A init")

print(A.attr) # name
```

Вывод:

```
Meta body
A body
Meta new for A
{'__qualname__': 'A', 'attr': 'new_name', '__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x0000000004AB4D90>}
Meta init for A
name
```

Как видно, метакласс - это не родитель класса, а то, что этот класс создает. Одна из целей метаклассов - менять классы на этапе их создания. Что  и произошло.

За большим, пожалуй, лучше сослаться на классическое объяснение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python